# access https site python (urllib2, requests)

Tags: python, https, urllib2, python-requests

I am trying to access the following site https://electionbuddy.com/elections/4322/results

I have tried using `handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)` etc and `requests`, but the webapp just sends back a page saying i dont have permission (no where for the user/pass to go). I tried firebug, but couldn't get anything obvious out of it. I can edit and attach if needed.

How could i go about logging in to such a site? As mentioned by Burhan, this case is where you need to "login save the cookies sent and pass them sent on the next request to the results page".

To follow up on that - why doesn't the following work

```
import requests
payload = {'user_username': 'xxxxxxxxx', 'user_password': 'xxxxxxx'}
r = requests.post("https://electionbuddy.com/login", data=payload)
r = requests.get('https://electionbuddy.com/elections/xxxx/results', cookies=r.cookies)
print r.text
```

There seems to be an authentication token, different from the session id. Not really sure how to go about doing this though...

Thanks

Comment: This is a bit too specific really. First you need to [login](https://electionbuddy.com/login) save the cookies sent and pass them sent on the next request to the results page.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this site makes a session cookie for you when you login to it.
Try first logging in and see if if throws you a cookie, and if so give the cookie to the page you need.
Are you familiar with cookielib?

```
from urllib2 import *
import cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = build_opener(
             HTTPHandler(), HTTPSHandler(), HTTPErrorProcessor(), 
             HTTPRedirectHandler(), HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
params = urllib.urlencode(dict(USER=user, PASSWORD=pw, action='Login'))

# Response here will have cookies, use info() to show
response = opener.open(loginurl, params)
print response.info()

# cookies automatically sent to the page you wanted
response2 = opener.open(your_url)
```

Comment: Vaguely. i do that and get
'HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity' using login page domain/login which exists

Answer (score 0):

I once had to access a  url that was username/password protected  and using the following method solved it

```
import urllib2
import base64
theurl = 'http://abc.com/A.htm'

username='AAA'
password='BBB'

req = urllib2.Request(theurl)


base64string = base64.encodestring(
            '%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader)
try:
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except IOError, e:
    print "It looks like the username or password is wrong."
content = handle.read()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not the solution, your answer provides [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and the site itself has a different login scheme.

Comment: Yep, tried it (found it on SO previously) and it fails in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Just adding answer so if some body stumbles up on the same problem.

The url given in question is a secured one i.e. uses HTTPS.

so HTTP basic authentication suggested elsewhere would obviously not work. Basic authentication works on plain http. Https is encryption.

Use some library such as [pycUrl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/quickstart.html) or [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPSConnection) might be the right choice which outright provide HTTPS support

Comment: HTTPS is at the transport level. Basic Auth is at the message level. These are orthogonal. Put another way,  Basic auth is equivalent of writing your name on a postcard, HTTPS is equivalent of putting the postcard in a sealed envelope. It is not unheard of to use HTTPS to add some security to basic auth and not advisable to use basic auth without HTTPS

Comment: I don't see how they affect each other. OP is assuming basic authentication to work as the authentication mechanism. He needs to follow the APIs which work with HTTPS given his URL above. The above description is not just relevant to the problem

Comment: Your statement 'HTTP basic authentication suggested elsewhere would obviously not work. Basic authentication works on plain http.' is false. Basic authentication works over HTTPS.

Comment: I disagree. Basic auth CAN work on https. But the original question seems to assume basic auth substituting https authentication mechanism which it is obviously is not. One needs to use HTTPS auth handler for an HTTPS website, whether or not you are using basic authentication or not.